# Paypal Payment Gateyway Integration in Laravel

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created sandbox accounts in paypal. But now I want to make the payment method LIVE. So what I need to do now? Do I need to register an App in paypal?
[image]I'm attaching one picture of Test account of paypal integration.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Paypal, register real account and you are able to get the credentials for starting to accept payments.

Comment: Thanks a lot @smartman I  just wanted to confirm about it :-)

Comment: Great, so if you can accept the question then it will be closed also.